# T-SQL MERGE unchanged target

Tags: sql-server, merge

I using this format for a MERGE clause:

```
DECLARE @Table (ColA int, ColB int, ID int)

INSERT @Table
SELECT changes.ColA,changes.ColB,Changes.Identity
FROM
(
  MERGE Target
  USING @SourceTable SOURCE
  ON Target.ID=Source.ID
  WHEN MATCHED AND target.ColA<>soruce.ColA or target.ColB<>source.ColB THEN 
    UPDATE SET
      Target.ColA=source.ColA,
      Target.ColB=source.ColB
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    INSERT(ColA,ColB)
    VALUES(Source.ColA,Source.ColB)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
  OUTPUT INSERTED.ColA,INSERTED.ColB,SOURCE.Identity
) AS changes(ColA,ColB,SOURCE.Identity)
```

I then use the `@Table` as the source for additional JOINS later on.  If there are no insert/updates to the TARGET table, then `@Table` is empty which is causing problems for the remainder of the whole query because there is nothing to JOIN on.

Is there a way to capture the `SOURCE` rows even if they are not manipulated on the `TARGET` side?

I need to use MERGE to retrieve Identity columns on INSERT/UPDATES.

Comment: Use `@SourceTable` itself then or `@Table UNION @SourceTable` for rows that don't exist in `@Table`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be best to add `IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0` condition to the rest of the script and just skip it when no records has been updated.
2. If no matter what has been updated in `Target` table all records from `@SourceTable` require further processing it might be best to just use `@SourceTable` instead of `OUTPUT` clause. No data in your `MERGE` statement is `OUTPUT` from the `Target` table.
3. If you would like to filter records from `@SourceTable` into `OUTPUT` clause even when no update on `Target` table is required you can perform "dummy update" on the records even where no values would actually change:

---

```
DECLARE @Table (ColA int, ColB int, ID int)
INSERT @Table
SELECT changes.ColA,changes.ColB,Changes.Identity
FROM (MERGE Target
USING (SELECT * FROM @SourceTable ) SOURCE
ON Target.ID=Source.ID
WHEN MATCHED /* AND target.ColA<>soruce.ColA or target.ColB<>source.ColB             */
             /* Remove condition and update even when no value would actually change */
THEN UPDATE SET Target.ColA=source.ColA,Target.ColB=source.ColB
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET INSERT(ColA,ColB) VALUES(Source.ColA,Source.ColB)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT INSERTED.ColA,INSERTED.ColB,SOURCE.Identity) AS changes(ColA,ColB,SOURCE.Identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture unmodified source records by capturing the `OUTPUT` of the merge statement. You need to introduce a dummy update:

```
DECLARE @dummy INT = 0;
MERGE ...
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE @dummy = @dummy
...
  OUTPUT INSERTED.ColA,INSERTED.ColB,SOURCE.Identity
```